# Django-allauth use for facebook login/signup on a json api

Tags: django, oauth, facebook-javascript-sdk, django-allauth, python-social-auth

I'm evaluating [django-allauth](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/) for my api. This api must support user signup via json over http as it's powering a phone app.

Reviewing the [example](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/tree/master/example/example/templates) demonstrates usage with django templates, i.e. html pages via traditional request-response cycle in a browser.

Is it possible to use django-allauth [views](https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/views.html) to power an app signup on a json api?
If not how would you solve this in django? (I've been avoiding django rest framework on this project btw)

would allauth provide a cookie or a jwt the client must put in the `Authorization` header?

update: [python-social-auth](https://python-social-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration/django.html) also looks popular

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ended up using

- https://github.com/agconti/cookiecutter-django-rest a good DRF base with a docker file
- https://github.com/RealmTeam/django-rest-framework-social-oauth2 handles login with facebook

also https://github.com/Tivix/django-rest-auth promises fb login plus the reset password flows for an app.

For a mobile+api blogpost read https://medium.com/@gabriel_gamil/react-native-expo-django-facebook-authentication-sign-in-83625c49da7 (I was using react native and this was a helpful article)

Comment: The above link demonstrates connection of facebook and google through web using react. However my requirement entails usage through mobile app using react-native. That's the difference that needs to be sorted out using social authentication.